# Import Java-Applet Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, applet, project

@ home i built a java applet in eclipse now i want to port it on my working computer...
eclipse version is the same as @ home and jdk also.
i get following error:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/ProgramApplet/bin/de'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent    ProgramApplet       Unknown Java Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly some kind of permissions error. Try deleteing the bin/de directory.